# Why is np.genfromtxt returning nan when reading the data files?

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I have a list containing the strings of my data files. When I read the data I expect to see a numpy array with 3 columns of floats but instead I just get nan.

```
FILE_NAMES = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv']
data = np.genfromtxt(FILE_NAMES, delimiter=',', skip_header=1)
print(data)
```

Here is an example of the data:

[image: More of the same below, float values for all 3 columns]

The values in all three of the columns are floats.

All it returns is:

```
nan
```

Can someone tell me what I need to change?

Comment: Use just one filename at a time, not a list of names.

Comment: @hpaulj yeah I have done that and it works fine but I am trying to adapt my code so it can work for many data files and all that is required is for the user to put these into the list rather than add any number of genfromtxt.

Comment: So you know how to use it correctly, and you want us explain why it doesn't work with wrong inputs!  This the wrong forum for that.

Comment: @hpaulj I just wasn't sure why it worked when I used the files separately but gave me a different output when I used a list of strings which I assumed would give me the same output. I wasn't sure where I went wrong and I know it's something small but I could really use the help. Thank you.

Comment: Referring to [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html): *If a list of strings or a generator returning strings is provided, each string is treated as **one line in a file**.* So, they do not refer to the datafiles with that names. For doing so, I think, you must use `np.loadtxt` if the data permit. If not, you must use `np.genfromtxt` in loops to import them separately.

Comment: @Ali_Sh, `loadtxt` uses a list of strings in the same way.  There's no shortcut to calling `genfromtxt` for each file.

Comment: @hpaulj You are right, I was wrong about `np.loadtxt` ability to handle multiple files at the same time. Thanks for correcting my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

That it didn't give an error initially puzzled me, but then I realized that:

`genfromtxt` accepts either a filename, or anything that gives it strings, like an open file, or a list of strings.  I often use such a list with copy-n-paste file samples.

It's in effect parsing this file

```
file1.csv
file2.csv
```

With 1 header line and 1 non-float data line.  Hence the `nan` data.

```
In [82]: alist = ['csv1.txt','csv2.txt','csv3.txt']
In [85]: data = np.genfromtxt(alist, dtype=None, encoding=True)
In [86]: data
Out[86]: array(['csv1.txt', 'csv2.txt', 'csv3.txt'], dtype='<U8')
```